# Finding in MongoDB using two keys with Express JS and Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, get

I need help. I'm using the command .find() in my web application (express JS and Node) but it doesn't work. I want to search with multiple words.

It's quite confusing because when I use the command $all, and I force two words (for exemple, salt or sugar), it works, but when I'm using variables it doesn't...

I'm attaching some images (the route itself and the function with its fetch):

[Here the route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRek7.png)

[Here the function with its fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQPnb.png)

Many thanks

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You have passed `ingredientBucar1` and `ingredientBucar2` with + sign

it will become a single string.
so You are passing 'sa1' and 'azucar' in ingredientBucar1 and ingredientBucar2, It will be passed to api as 'sa1' and 'azucar'

To overcome this You can pass it in post api and get in `req.body`
or you can pass it through search params or pass them through 2 different query params like

`your_api_endpoint/:ingredientBucar1/:ingredientBucar2`

Answer (score 0):

It's me, here is the code:

FUNCIONES.JS
function buscarPorIngredientes(){

```
// let ingredienteABuscar01=document.getElementById("buscarIngrediente01","buscarIngrediente02","buscarIngrediente03","buscarIngrediente04","buscarIngrediente05").value;

let ingredienteABuscar1=document.getElementById("buscarIngrediente01").value;
let ingredienteABuscar2=document.getElementById("buscarIngrediente02").value;

fetch("/busquedaIngredientes/"+ingredienteABuscar1+ingredienteABuscar2
    
)
  .then(function(res){

    return res.json();

},
)

.then(function(datos){

    for (let i = 0; i < datos.length; i++){

    document.getElementById("divBuscarPorIngrediente").innerHTML+=
    `<div>
    <h4>${datos[i].nombre}</h4>
    <p>INGREDIENTES: ${datos[i].ingredientes}</p>
    <img src="${datos[i].imagen}" width="300"></a></p>
    </div>`;
    }
},
);
```

};

INDEX.JS

`app.get("/busquedaIngredientes/:ingredientes",buscarPorIngredientes2);
function buscarPorIngredientes2(req,res){

```
const ingredienteABuscar1=req.params.ingredientes;
const ingredienteABuscar2=req.params.ingredientes;

app.locals.db.collection("cocteles").find({ingredientes: {$all: [

    // ingredienteABuscar1,
    // ingredienteABuscar2

    "sal",
    "azucar"

]}},
    
    console.log(ingredienteABuscar2),
    
)

.toArray(
    function(err,datos){

        if(err!=null){

            console.log(err);
            
        }
        
        else{

            console.log(datos);
            res.send(datos);

        }
    }
)
```

};`